# Presigned Url vs Object url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When the bucket and its objects are private, we cannot access the objects with Object URL. We would need to use presigned url. But if the objects are public, then what would be different between a presigned url and object url is ?

[image]

Comment: You can set the duration for presigned urls.

Comment: ok..after the duration, it will expire, but Object URL wont expire.  Are there anything else ? my main motive is to understand if presigned url has any advantage over the Object URL for a public object.

Comment: If an object is Public, then a pre-signed URL is not required. It's like asking whether a house with open doors requires a key to enter. It does not.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thats make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html):

- Keep the objects as **private**
- Do *not* use a Bucket Policy
- When generating the pre-signed URL, you can specify an **expiry period** (eg the URL is valid for 5 minutes)
- When somebody uses the pre-signed URL, S3 will **verify** the signature and the expiry time
- If they are valid, S3 will provide access to the private object

Comment: good but my question is in case of public objects. I'm aware of use case and issue 
of presigned url when accessing private object.